# Google Maps Custom Marker Icon based on greater than field value

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have created a Web Map with Google Maps API and defined my marker icons to be custom according to the following code:

```
var customIcons = {
      Biotechnology: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      Health: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
        }
}
```

However I have not found a way to define my custom marker icons if I use a > or < symbol. and replace "Biotechnology" or "Health" with something like

```
var customIcons = {
          Budget > 150000: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
          },
          Budget < 150000: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            }
    }
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
var image = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png';
var image2 = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png';

  for (var i = 0; i < ... ; i++)
  {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(..., ...);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            if (  Budget > 150000) {
              icon: image;
            } else {
              icon: image2;
            }
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
     });

  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I get an error: SyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters
 

if (  Budget > 150000: {